# What security does Silverlight's clientaccesspolicy add?

Tags: silverlight, web-services, security, cross-domain

Yesterday I got a question from a collegue about Silverlight's crossdomain access policy mechanism. I've not used it before, so I read up a bit on it. I think that I do understand how to configure it, but I don't understand the security implications.

If I for example have the following setup:

- http://somesite.com/html-hosting-silverlight-app.html
- http://somesite.com/silverlight-app.xap
- http://othersite.com/service.svc
- http://othersite.com/clientaccesspolicy.xml

In this case the clientaccess policy of othersite can enable the silverlight-app at somesite to use the othersite.com/service.svc service. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) this is an ensurance of the service that it is safe:

> By opting-in, a service states that
>   the operations it exposes can safely
>   be invoked by a Silverlight control,
>   without potentially damaging
>   consequences to the data that the
>   service stores.

What I don't understand is how this provides any real security benefit. The service is just another soap service, which can be called from any soap client, using any crafted call parameters. If I fire up wcftestclient against http://othersite/service.svc I can just bypass the clientaccesspolicy.xml and do whatever I want.

So, what security does the clientaccesspolicy.xml really add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to prevent [Cross Site Request Forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) where a malicioius Silverlight application can perform actions on behalf of the user. Having a [properly configured clientaccesspolicy.xml](http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=102) ensures that the request comes from a trusted Silverlight application.

As far as invoking the service directly, normally methods that modify resources on the server should be protected with authentication to ensure that only authorized users can invoke them.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, it's part of the silverlight sandbox on the user's computer. The silverlight sandbox prevents a malicious silverlight app from using authentication cookies stored in the user's browser to perform actions on other sites. If the site promises (through a clientaccess.xml file) that it is safe to allow any silverlight app to access the site, with access to the user's cookies, the sandbox is opened. Is that right?

Comment: @AndersAbel: I don't think it has anything to do with cookies. Silverlight just won't open communication whenever the clientaccesspolicy.xml is not found or isn't matching the request.

Comment: @the_drow: If it's not about cookies etc, then what is the security benefit of having the Silverlight sandbox check if communication is okay with the server before allowing the connection?

Comment: @AndersAbel: So it won't access APIs it shouldn't.

Comment: @AndersAbel You are right. Cookies are included in the requests. See also http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=107